# How to insert the current selected row in Datagridview to the Database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

```
     For i As Integer = Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            Dim SDA1 As New MySqlDataAdapter
            Dim bSource1 As New BindingSource
            Dim dbDataSet1 As New DataTable
            qty = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
            auth = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value()
            title = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value()
            callnumber = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value()
            shelf = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value()
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "Insert into returnedlist(quantity,author,title ,call_number,shelf,student_id,due_date,date_added)  values('" & qty & "','" & auth & "','" & title & "','" & callnumber & "','" & shelf & "','" & TextBox2.Text.ToString & "','" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "', Now())"
            COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
            SDA1.SelectCommand = COMMAND
            SDA1.Fill(dbDataSet1)
            bSource1.DataSource = dbDataSet1
            Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = bSource1
            SDA1.Update(dbDataSet1)
        Next


    **Code for Select**
 ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "Author" Then
                Dim Query As String
                Query = "Select id as 'ID', quantity as 'Qty',author as 'Author',title as 'Title',call_number as 'Call Number',location as 'Shelf #' from librarydb.blist where author like'%" & TextBox1.Text & "%' ORDER by author"
                COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
                SDA.SelectCommand = COMMAND
                If SDA.Fill(dbDataSet) Then
                    bSource.DataSource = dbDataSet
                    DataGridView1.DataSource = bSource
                    TextBox1.Text = ""
                    ComboBox2.Text = ""

                Else
                    TextBox1.Text = ""
                    ComboBox2.Text = ""
                    MessageBox.Show("No Results found", "Informed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
                End If
```

what i want to do is i want to insert in the db what i have selected row in the Datagridview.

The code works but the problem is :
**even if i choose to select the row3, it always fall inserting to db the row1 in the datagridview.**

Does it have to do on the properties of my Datagridview?

Comment: How do you fill the datagridview? Are you using an MySqlDataAdapter with a correct SELECT query?

Comment: yes sir im using mysqlDataadapter

Comment: The MySqlDataAdapter.Update method could automatically update your database table without resorting to a loop over your rows. You should use the same adapter that you have used to fill the grid (declare it globally) and be sure that your query returns the PrimaryKey of the table.

Comment: sir this is my code for query how can i insert my primary key that youre talking about

Comment: Query = "Select quantity as 'Qty',author as 'Author',title as 'Title',call_number as 'Call Number',location as 'Shelf #' from librarydb.blist where title like'%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"

Comment: ive declared it globally but noyhing change it still insert's row into db

Comment: The MySqlDataAdapter.Update method executes every action required to update your database table working together with a MySqlCommandBuilder but to work it need to know the PrimaryKey of your database table. Look at it in your database tool (MySqlWorkbench or ??) then load in your SELECT command (SELECT yourPrimaryKeyColumn, etc....) What is your primary key column?

Comment: im using mysql workbench and my primary key out there is id

Comment: sir i've included in my select command my primary key which is ID.But nothing have change still row 1 is being inserted to the db

Answer (score 0):

The `Update` method of the `MySqlDataAdapter` has the capability to update all the rows present in the DataTable passed as input that have the `RowState` property different from the value `Unchanged`.

When you edit a DataGridView binded to a DataTable the changes made on the grid are immediately reflected in the underlying DataTable and the row edited will have its [RowState property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate(v=vs.110).aspx) changed accordingly to the edit made.

To make this work you need a couple of things.

First declare globally the MySqlDataAdapter used to retrieve the datatable

```
Dim SDA1 As MySqlDataAdapter
```

then in the code that loads the datatable be sure to include also the column that is your primary key

```
' Here ID is assumed to be your primarykey'
SDA1 = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT ID, ...... FROM returnedlist", connection)
SDA1.Fill(yourDataTable)
Dim bSource1 As New BindingSource
bSource1.DataSource = yourDataTable
dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource1
```

Now you use an [MySqlCommandBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommandbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) to automatically create the InsertCommand, UpdateCommand and DeleteCommand properties of your MySqlDataAdapter

```
Dim builder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(SDA1)
```

Finally, when you are ready to update your data, you write simply

```
Dim yourBindingSource = dataGridView1.DataSource As BindingSource
SDA1.Update(yourBindingSource.DataSource as DataTable)
```

No loop required on your grid rows and manually building the InsertCommand and its parameters

For an overview on how a class derived from DbDataAdapter is supposed to work you could read the [MSDN reference here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1z2bkx2(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: thanks sir i will try to understand this code and update you if it really worked

Comment: Sir if i am going to include Selecting my primary key, it also must be inserted in the Db. **Please check above** i've included my select query

Comment: and i might have got Primary key duplication error.

Comment: Sir can you provide a Insert command that matched in your Select query
??

Comment: Did you try the code provided? If yes did you get errors? The whole point of the code above is to avoid manually typing INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE commands in response to the edit made on the grid. If the ID column is an autoincrement column then the INSERT command will be aware of this and will not try to add a value for it.

Comment: Do i have also need to change my insert query??